# Flutter/Firestore – how to compare 2 documents?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am writing a language dictionary using Flutter with Firestore.
I have database named ‘Spanish’ and 2 documents ‘easy’ and ‘difficult’.
Each document is a set pairs - a key is original Spanish word and the value is translation of this word.

I want to find which keys (original Spanish words) appears in both ‘easy’ and ‘difficult’ documents.
My query (which is not working) is:

```
var myResult = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Spanish')
      .doc('easy')
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) { 
      if (snapshot != null)    { 
          snapshot.data()?.forEach((key, value) {  
          var myData2 = **checkIfSelected**(key); 
          print(myData2) ;
       });

Future<dynamic> checkIfSelected(String key) async {  
  bool ifSelected = false;

  var myResult2 = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Spanish')
      .doc('difficult')
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) {   
      if (snapshot != null) {
         snapshot.data()?.forEach((k, v) {
         if (k == key) {
          ifSelected = true;
         } 
    }
  }); 

  return ifSelected;
}
```

Why is not working? I made a lot of displays which I removed from quoted code, but function **checkIfSelected** returns **Instance of 'Future'** instead of bool. This is async function with await, so as I understand it should not return Futures.
I tried make a change:

```
var myData2 = await checkIfSelected(key);
```

but got error:

> The await expression can only be used in an async function.
> Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'.dart(await_in_wrong_context)

But `checkIfSelected` is already an `async` function.

Any ideas what I did wrong in my code, or maybe there is another approach to this problem?

Comment: Just want to comment. Aside from your confusing question. This looks like a bad data structure. A single document (easy or difficult) holds all the items for the words (dictionary), that is a terrible idea. And the reason why your question is confusing it that, your title is "how to compare 2 documents" but your description is about "async/await". What exactly do you want to solve here? Also, why does a dictionary have difficulty levels? Is this a quiz app instead? I'm not entirely sure what type of "compare" you want.

Comment: When I said 'compare documents' I meant to make something as 'matching sequential files'. Each document is a dictionary, collection of words and translations, and I wanted to know which words are in both documents. According to my test my code is not working because a sync function with await is returning Instance of 'Future' instead of bool.

Answer (score 0):

Try This way,

```
  void getData() async {
    var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Spanish').doc('easy').get();

    var data = snapshot.data();

    for (var key in (data?.keys.toList() ?? [])) {
      var myData2 = await checkIfSelected(key);
      print(myData2);
    }
  }

  Future<bool> checkIfSelected(String key) async {
    var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Spanish').doc('difficult').get();

    var data = snapshot.data();

    for (var k in (data?.keys.toList() ?? [])) {
      return k == key;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Note:

Asynchronous calls don't work with .forEach(), you need to use traditional loops. Why? This [article](https://www.coreycleary.me/why-does-async-await-in-a-foreach-not-actually-await/) explains it very well. I just discovered that Dart and Node.JS are almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

I write another approach to get the words that occur in both easy and hard documents:

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getEasy() async {
    DocumentSnapshot myResult = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Spanish')
        .doc('easy')
        .get();
    return myResult.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getDifficult() async {
    DocumentSnapshot myResult = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Spanish')
        .doc('difficult')
        .get();
    return myResult.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  }

  Future<List<String>> getOccurrences() async {
    List<String> spanishWordsThatOccursOnBoth = [];
    Map<String, dynamic> easy = await getEasy();
    Map<String, dynamic> difficult= await getDifficult();

    easy.forEach((key, value) {
      if (difficult.containsKey(key)) {
        spanishWordsThatOccursOnBoth.add(key);
      }
    });

    return spanishWordsThatOccursOnBoth;
  }
```

you can call it like this, and it will search for them and return a list with those Spanish words:

```
List<String> OcurrencesSpanishWords = await getOccurrences();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `async`/`await` you should **not** use `then`.

With just the former, it'd be:

```
Future<dynamic> checkIfSelected(String key) async {  
  bool ifSelected = false;

  var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Spanish')
      .doc('difficult')
      .get()

  if (snapshot != null) {
    snapshot.data()?.forEach((k, v) {
    if (k == key) {
      ifSelected = true;
    } 
  }

  return ifSelected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code has a missing async keyword.

```dart
var myResult = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Spanish')
      .doc('easy')
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) async { // MISSING async
      if (snapshot != null)    { 
          snapshot.data()?.forEach((key, value) {  
          var myData2 = await checkIfSelected(key); 
          print(myData2) ;
       });
```

Comment: I tried but I was getting error - as BIS Tech explained: "Asynchronous calls don't work with .forEach(), you need to use traditional loops."